How do I make it so spaces are ignored in lists? (python)
So I have a project I'm doing that has a part where I have to convert user input into a list.
numbers = input("Enter a list of numbers seperated by spaces.")
numList = list(numbers)
print(numList)

What I want is this:
Enter a list of numbers seperated by spaces.1 3 5
['1', '3', '5']
instead I get this:
Enter a list of numbers seperated by spaces.1 3 5
['1', ' ', '3', ' ', '5']
Another thing I've noticed is that it also doesn't like double digit numbers that much. This issue is definitely something I can fix with converting to an integer, but who knows, I may just be stupid.
I've tried using the list function's extra stuff, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work how I want.

Once you've read the documentation for str.split you'll want to figure out how to validate the input to ensure that the values are integers

There is a function in Python called "string.split(separator, maxsplit)
Here if you provide "space" as separator, you'll achieve your goal.
user_input = input("Enter the numbers: ")

user_input_list = user_input.split(' ')

print(user_input_list)

OUTPUT:
Enter the numbers: 1 12 13 14 255
['1', '12', '13', '14', '255']


You can conveniently use user_input.split() to split on all/any whitespace

You can use below code to get exact answer in which you can split the user input and filter out the result.
numbers = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by spaces.")
list_content = numbers.split(" ")
result = [x for x in list_content if x != ""]
print(result)


result = [str(x) for x in list_content if x != " "]   # x shouldn't be equal to " ".

No elements of list_content could possibly be equal to "". Why would you call str() on something that's already a str type?

Below input values have extra 2 spaces between value 3 and 5, so based on that we have to check !="".
Example:-
Enter a list of numbers separated by spaces.1 3    5
OUTPUT (2 extra spaces between 3 and 5):
['1', '3', ' ', ' ', '5']
Enter a list of numbers separated by spaces.1 3 5
OUTPUT (only once space between all the numbers):
['1', '3', '5']
